# How to start "Chrome" (or equivalent) as a thread instead of process?

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt, browser

We have an app, which is written in Qt/C++. Its GUI is in Html/Css/JS.

The app works well on the Chrome & Edge. On desktops, the app invokes the OS browser as a separate process. The browser connects via Websocket to the app and exchange the messages for the display purposes. This works well.

However, this doesn't work in the mobiles. Because invoking a browser as a separate process, would send the actual app to background in Android & iOS.
Now many answers on SO suggests to use the mobile webview, which comes built-in. But, the Webview in Android doesn't fulfill all the requirements in all the devices. And the iOS Webview is simply substandard & weak.

**Question**: Is there a way to start any chrome-like browser as a thread of the app itself?

The intention is to keep the app in the foreground without compromising on the Webview limitations. Fine with source code integration & compilation, if required.

Comment: Chrome is an independent application without API in C++ for it. I don't believe you may do it unless there is a Chrome library for C++ that I didn't know about.

Comment: This is based on Chromium which represents the base for the Chrome project: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-overview.html

Comment: @AlexanderV, we have tried this in past around 1+ year back. There are 2 issues. (1) The integration of the whole WebEngineView is too big from the memory perspective. (2) It's not available for the mobiles. For mobile, Qt still uses the native webview. Hence the problem still persists. Is there any update from the Qt side on this regard?

Comment: You probably can use clone system call, I suppose they have not yet implemented seccomp syscall filtering. Just watch at the ARM abi, implement the syscall in assembly and use futex syscall when you need a mutex like synchronistation primitive. It is actualy simpler than having to deal with the messy posix thread layer.

Comment: @Oliv, sorry unable to understand your comment. Is it posted in a wrong question by mistake? :-)

Comment: The answer to this question is yours ;-)

Comment: @Oliv, can you elaborate more as an answer? My requirement is that, I want to start Firefox or Chrome as a thread instead of a separate process.

Comment: I don't know iOS, but speaking on Android: You can't start another app as a thread within your app. That'd create all sorts of security issues. You could build your own in-app browser based on Chromium, but it would be difficult, and when finished you'd have just re-implemented Android WebView. :) What's the specific problem with WebView? Have you looked into using Chrome Custom Tabs, or GeckoView?

Comment: @ppm, Android webview is not consistent with WebRTC in all the mobiles, but the chrome browser is good enough. The file system is broken in the webview. There are other minor issues as well. BTW, I don't intend to start it as a process, but as a thread. Is recent Firefox 6 mb binary useful in this regard? Custom tabs  are not useful as they are different processes from the app.

Answer (score 1):

Web engines are the the driving bodies for how a browser runs. As chrome is based on chromium web engine you need to modify the engine accordingly.

Chrome uses process for each tab while Firefox uses a thread instead.

Chrome architecture has two main processes **Browser Process** and **Renderer Process**. Browser UI is running in Browser Process and When you open new tab in Chrome browser, for each tab a new process is gets created called as **Renderer Process**. Renderer process handles rendering of your HTML contents.

Suppose you have opened 10 tabs in your chrome which leads to creation of 10 Renderer process and 1 browser process.

Why separate Renderer process for each tab ?

Suppose at any point of time while browsing through internet because of some reason some tab crashed, then only that renderer process gets killed and other process are still alive. Your 9 tabs are still responsive and working.
As browser UI is running in different process. Browser UI wont get hanged in general and its responsive enough.
As each renderer is running as different process, shared data access is difficult(thread can access shared data) which provides inter tab data security.
There are many other process running on and having there own purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs). This approach is in between a WebView and opening a link externally in Chrome.

As far as I know everything happens in the browser's process, but you can warm it up via a special Service. You can also pre-render content via [`mayLaunchUrl`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsSession.html#mayLaunchUrl%28android.net.Uri,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E%29).

Comment: The app's GUI is in html5, so browser is a must. But I think the app itself won't remain in foreground once the custom tab is opened. How to fix that? (We explored & ruled out this approach due to this)